# PHP eval() - reliably filter file functions

Tags: php, eval

The title sums it up pretty well. What's a reliable way of preventing the execution of functions that interact with files? We are talking about <strike>evil</strike> `eval()`.

I have full access to the string that is about to be evaluated. I was thinking about simply removing the backstick operator, and replacing file function names (along with exec) with ones that do effectively nothing, but I'm unsure how reliable this approach is.

Example:

**PHP code**

```
eval("file_get_contents('passwords.ini')");
```

Currently this is replaced by, before execution:

**PHP code**

```
eval("fn_zero('passwords.ini')");
```

---

**EDIT**

Concerning <strike>evil</strike> eval(). What I am doing here is the execution of admin-created, database stored PHP code in a module based content-management-system. Editing the code requires an additional level of authentication that is separate from the main admin login, it is not entirely untrusted user input.

The admin can butcher his/her site if that's his/her intention, that is not my concern. My concern is the prevention of viewing the underlying PHP code of the CMS.

Addendum: each site has its own webroot and database. They can't harm each other this way.

Comment: Keep the following Quote in mind: If eval() is the answer, you're almost certainly asking the wrong question. `-- Rasmus Lerdorf, BDFL of PHP`

Comment: Can you please tell us what you are trying to functionaly accomplish? Because eval() is probably a bad idea. sidenote: Personaly I have never needed eval to fix any problem.

Comment: I'm tasked with building a 'programmable module' for a module based CMS. Administrators can - along predefined ones like gallery, formatted text, etc - create custom modules, that display into their own containers. I don't care if they butcher their site, because they are (should be) aware of the consequences. What I'm primarily achieving to do is to prevent access to the underlying CMS php code.

Comment: Blacklists are almost impossible to get 100% secure, because you're pretty much guaranteed to miss something. Whitelists are always better, but almost impossible to do if accepting an arbitrary string to `eval()`. A better idea approach is to define some sort of mini-language where the user can select a combination of functions and the result is computed without `eval()`.

Comment: `eval()` is never the answer. `eval()` is the question. The answer is '[NO](http://i.imgur.com/9wTqMqb.gif)'.

Comment: Sounds like what you need is a templating language, such as Smarty or Twig: the "module" would be defined as a template, and the template's compiler takes care of the security restrictions for you.

Comment: @IMSoP I'm looking into that, but it's not really what I need. I have to create standard PHP-code support for that module, because it is to interact with a custom framework, database: as if it was native PHP code being executed at the time the module was displayed.

Comment: If you have to use eval. Which i'd recommend highly against it. The only thing you should be passing into `eval` would be pre-defined strings with absolutely no user input.

Comment: I greatly appreciate the help already, but I'm aware of the dangers eval() presents, and that wasn't the point of my question. I have edited my post to offer more context.

Comment: If this task was given to me, I would do a more thorough review of the requirements: the users should be interacting with a standard API, which should therefore be possible to expose via template callbacks. If the users can genuinely write any PHP they like, security is meaningless, exposure of source code is not something that can be prevented, and the solution is a water-tight contract rather than technical prevention.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer the question as asked, "sanitizing" the eval input is not possible. Simple example:

```
eval("\$f=strrev('stnetnoc_teg_elif');\$f('passwords.ini');");
```

Viable options to execute user-provided code are [sandboxing](http://php.net/manual/en/runkit.sandbox.php) or a userland VM  like https://github.com/ircmaxell/PHPPHP.

Answer (score 0):

Next code will help to avoid executions of functions you want to avoid:

```
//Just a code example
//Array of functions which should be avoid (file functions)
$patterns = [
                'chgrp',
                'chmod',
                'chown',
                'clearstatcache',
                'copy',
                'delete',
                'fclose',
                'fflush',
                'file_put_contents',
                'flock',
                'fopen',
                'fputs',
                'fwrite',
                'ftruncate',
                'lchgrp',
                'lchown',
                'link',
                'mkdir',
                'move_uploaded_file',
                'parse_ini_file',
                'pclose',
                'popen',
                'rename',
                'rmdir',
                'set_file_buffer',
                'symlink',
                'tempnam',
                'tmpfile',
                'touch',
                'umask',
                'unlink',
            ];

foreach ($patterns as $key => $value) {
    $patterns[$key] = '/~' . $value . '\(.*\)/U'; //~ is mask here
}

//clear of dangerous file operations
$conditions = '~' . $conditions; //set mask
$conditions = str_replace(' ', '~', $conditions); //set mask
$conditions = preg_replace($patterns, '~true', $conditions);//here replaced to 'true' but you can use here your own custom function
$conditions = str_replace('~', ' ', $conditions); //remove mask

if (!empty($conditions)) {
    eval($conditions);
}
```

Expression like "mkdir() && is_single(77) && copy('path') && mycopy('a') && copy2('b')" will be translated to: "true && is_single(77) && true && mycopy('a') && copy2('b')"